# how to handle the response type from servlet in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

Below is the scenario in one of our application

CLIENT > ajax call > Servlet

The service returns the generated powerpoint presentation and the response type is set to `application/vnd.ms-powerpoint`.

Any idea how this has to be handled in the client?

Should it be consumed as binary data or should we go back to ActivexObjects or any other techniques?

Any thoughts would be useful, thanks!

Comment: why not just assume that a browser will handle it? Normally by showing "Save as" dialog?